# Update key in c# Dictionary (ConcurrentDictionary)

Tags: c#, dictionary, concurrency

I want to add an UpdateKey method to an observable wrapper class around a ConcurrentDictionary. Something like this:

```
private bool UpdateKeyWithNotification(TKey key1, TKey key2)
{
    if (key1.Equals(key2)) return false;
    TValue value;
    var result = _dictionary.TryRemove(key1, out value);
    if (!result) return false;
    result = _dictionary.TryAdd(key2, value);
    if (result) NotifyObserversOfChange();
    return result;
}
```

Obviously this operation is no longer atomic as it does a remove and then add. I don't have much of a performance requirement on UpdateKeyWithNotification as it will be used seldom but I'd like to have some type of execution guarantee for the backing `_dictionary` between `TryRemove` and `TryAdd`. I could add some type of RWMutex or a lock object around the TryRemove and TryAdd operations. But that'd probably mean I'd also have to add lock statements around all other methods in the class. Is there an alternative to my solution?

Comment: Why does it need to be atomic? Could you describe a scenario where changing the key of a value (as opposed to changing the value of a key) needs to be an atomic operation?

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot use `ConcurrentDictionary` to do this atomically with any of its built in methods (and note that the [SyncRoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.system-collections-icollection-syncroot?view=netframework-4.7.2) property won't help as it's not supported.

You can use an external synchronization mechanism, but then you're immediately not gaining anything from `ConcurrentDictionary`, in fact making it less concurrent.

Since you're essentially re-keying some data, I would suggest that you derive a thread-safe wrapper from [DictionaryBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.dictionarybase?view=netframework-4.7.2) and add your specialize method.